# Handle dataset views database queries in microservices architecture

Tags: node.js, database, design-patterns, microservices

I am developing a microservices-based software, where each service has its own database containing 'core' objects along with some others that are partially replicated or contain additional data.

In the frontend, I have an Admin dashboard with tables/datasets to display various data. However, sometimes the data needed for a table/dataset is spread across multiple services. For instance, consider a table/dataset displaying appointments. One service manages appointments and all scheduling data related to them (such as duration, start date, and end date), while another service handles location data (including advanced location details). I want to display both sets of data in the same table.

The challenge lies in merging the data from both services.

Is there any approach I could take to solve this problem?

I attempted to solve this by making requests to both services and then iterating through the arrays, creating dictionaries with IDs to retrieve each object by their ID. However, I am concerned that this approach could lead to issues such as data inconsistency and high processing load due to iterating through the arrays for each request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.